# Keep getting Run Time error for a Kattis Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to solve this problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/anotherbrick).

And when I submit my final code I keep getting a Run Time error. I am not sure what's wrong with my code.

```
# @Author Gansaikhan Shur
# Another Brick in the Wall 

import sys

# if len(sys.argv) < 2:
#    sys.exit("{}: needs an input file!".format(sys.argv[0]))
#    exit()

sys_input = sys.argv[1]

with open(sys_input, "r") as f:
    data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    hw_num = data[0].split()
    len_bricks = data[1].split()
    # Assigning to variables
    height = int(hw_num[0])
    width = int(hw_num[1])
    num_bricks = hw_num[2]

currHeight = 0
for i in range(height):
    currHeight = i+1
    brick_width = 0
    for j in len_bricks:
        brick_width += int(j)
        if currHeight == height and brick_width == width:
            print("YES")
            exit()
        if brick_width == width:
            brick_width = 0
            continue
        elif brick_width > width:
            print("NO")
            exit()
        else:
            continue
    currHeight += 1
```

Please let me know what I can do to get this code accepted to kattis.com. Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves when I submit it to Kattis.com I get "Run Time Error" under the status bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run time error can mean:

- you got a error that occures at run time only
- **you got a wrong result** (see below the code block - your data gathering was wrong)
- your code runs too long

---

**Problem 1:**

Your code does not increment the height:

> ```
>  if brick_width == width:
>             brick_width = 0
>             continue
> ```

if you have data like `bricks = [1]*10000000` your code will run loooong, because you never increment the height you are at. You need to process the whole list until you get a "NO".

**Problem 2:**

Your method to read in data for this task is wrong - it is not *file based*. See [the documentation for python on Kattis](https://open.kattis.com/help/python3#solving) -you need to read from `sys.stdin` (code below).

---

You can streamline it:

```
def can_he_do_it(h,w,bricks):
    height = 0
    cur_w = 0

    # remove this line for kattis.com
    print("Project: Height: {} Width: {} with {}".format(h,w,bricks)) 

    # process all bricks - not the height or anythin else with range
    # bricks is all you got, place them down one by one, check lenght/height
    # and return False if you are too wide or not high enough
    # return True if you are high enough
    for brick in bricks:
        cur_w += brick        # add to current width and check

        if cur_w > w:         # too wide
            return False
        elif cur_w == w:      # exaclty correct, next row
            height += 1
            cur_w = 0

        if height == h:       # reach target heigth
            return True

    return False              # too few materials


def result(b):
     print("YES" if b else "NO") 

# replace with your number-read-code
result( can_he_do_it(2, 10, [5,5,5,5,5,5,]) )
result( can_he_do_it(2, 10, [5,5,5,3,5,5,]) )
result( can_he_do_it(2, 10, [5,5,5,]) )
```

Output:

```
Project: Height: 2 Width: 10 with [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
YES

Project: Height: 2 Width: 10 with [5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5]
NO

Project: Height: 2 Width: 10 with [5, 5, 5]
NO
```

---

Use:

```
import sys 

data = []
for i in sys.stdin:
    data.append(i)

data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in data if line]
height, width, *_ = map(int,data[0].split())  # read 2 values, ignore rest, cast to int
bricks = list(map(int, data[1].split()))      # use all bricks, cast to int

# replace with your number-read-code
can_he_do_it(height, width, bricks)
```

to get:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Your solution looks way better than mine. But I still having error submitting it to Kattis.com. I am reading the file using sys.argv[1]. But the website keep telling me I have a runtime error